# Sitemap_generator produces sitemap at unknown URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sitemap

I'm using the [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator) gem to produce sitemaps for my site.

Producing a sitemap locally works fine, and I can access the sitemap at `http://localhost:3000/sitemap1.xml.gz`.

After deploying to Heroku and running

```
heroku run rake sitemap:refresh --app myapp-prod
```

I get this:

```
In /app/public/
+ sitemap1.xml.gz                                        254 links /    4.74 KB
+ sitemap_index.xml.gz                                  1 sitemaps /  231 Bytes
Sitemap stats: 254 links / 1 sitemaps / 0m06s
```

So far so good - however, when trying to access my sitemap at `https://myapp.com/sitemap1.xml.gz`, I get a 404 error. I've tried the following ways to resolve this but none have worked:

1. Call `git add` for the two locally generated xml files, push them to Heroku, and call `heroku run rake sitemap:refresh --app myapp-prod` to update the locally generated URLs with my production URLs. However the file is not being refreshed, it stays exactly the same as generated locally, even though the same message as above is being returned.
2. Producing the sitemap into a custom path, e.g. public/shared/. But the error persists when accessing `https://myapp.com/shared/sitemap1.xml.gz`.
3. All possible and impossible URL combinations, like `https://myapp.com/public/sitemap1.xml.gz` (which of course were never going to work, but wanted to leave no stone unturned)

Any ideas as to what could cause this behaviour, and where the sitemap might be stored?

Answer (score 4):

After some further research I finally figured out what the issue was.

Since Heroku uses a read-only filesystem, the sitemaps can't be generated to the `public` directory. This is explained in more detail here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

The solution that worked for me in the end was generating the sitemaps into my Amazon S3 storage, as described [here](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku).

Answer (score 0):

What did you do about uploading your sitemap to Google Web Master tools because by default it wants the sitemap to live at http://www.yoursite.com/.....

I have my sitemap hosted in Amazon S3 and it's referenced in my robots.txt file but I need to tell Google Web Master Tools where to find it.

Any advice?

Comment: Nevermind, I found this blog post on adding your amazons3 website to google webmaster tools and adding the sitemap there - http://stanicblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/how-to-add-your-sitemap-file-located-in.html